# System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() remains open in background after closing WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, messagebox

Recently i tried to implement System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() in WPF project. I am using the full screen application using xaml tag " WindowState="Maximized" " . Now the issue is related to messagebox, suppose if user is getting messagebox when main window is open then user 1st have to click the messagebox popup then only he can perform any other action. But whenever user minimize the application without closing the message box. It will remain open in background and if we close the application it will be in background

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox is meant for showing a dialog box for some sort of user confirmation. Therefore the behavior is as per the standard.

However, If you need to allow the user to continue working with the parent window without forcing him to close the child window, you can use a Window with required content instead of a MessageBox:

```
private void btnPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  new Window() { Owner = this}.Show(); // Pass this as owner to allow closing child window when application closes
  MessageBox.Show("Popup Shown");
}
```

You can create a custom WPF window class with UI as per your requirement.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since Message Boxes are ***child*** of the current window, it is *always* opened as a dialog, it is prompt. So it is *not* possible to ignore it and continue using the current or application window. If you want to open it so that it can be ignored and let the user interact with the application, you will l have to make another form which can act as a message box.